# Navigation Bar Transparente en Android 10 Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Estoy realizando la adecuación de estilos en Android 10 pero al tratar de hacer la Navigation Bar del dispositivo "Transparente", no lo respeta.

¿Alguien que tenga una solución efectiva para este Target de Api que me pueda ayudar por favor?

Anexo imágenes del issue.

[image: Aqui se muestra que el Status bar si lo respeta pero la Navigation bar no.]

[image: Este es el código en un Resource style]

Comment: Nota: Cualquier tipo de Tip o comentario es muy bien recibido. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Programaticamente puedes cambiar el `NavigationBar` a color transparente de esta forma:

```
private  void setWindowFlag(Window window, final int bits, boolean on) {
    Window win = getWindow();
    WindowManager.LayoutParams winParams = win.getAttributes();
    if (on) {
        winParams.flags |= bits;
    } else {
        winParams.flags &= ~bits;
    }
    win.setAttributes(winParams);
}

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Window window = getWindow();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            int windowManager = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS;
            windowManager = windowManager | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION;
            setWindowFlag(window, windowManager, false);
            //window.setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            window.setNavigationBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        }


}
```

Comment: Y esta también funciona para la API 29 en adelante?